# Migrate Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine to Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

after Microsoft marked the BuildEngine.Engine and BuildEngine.Project as obsolete i have tried to use the new proposal from Microsoft how you can see it underneath. But i have no idea where i can integrate the xmlprojectfile. Is here someone who knows the solution of this problem?

**The XML project file content**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectToBuild Include ="myproject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>  
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)"
      Properties="Configuration=Debug" StopOnFirstFailure="true" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**The old and working version (but obsolete)**

```
Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine engine = new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine();
engine.DefaultToolsVersion = "4.0";
engine.RegisterLogger(new ConsoleLogger());
Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project project = new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project(engine);
project.Load(xmlprojectfile);
if (!project.Build())
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**The new not working verison**

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection collection = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection();
collection.DefaultToolsVersion = "4.0";
collection.RegisterLogger(new ConsoleLogger());
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(collection);
if (!project.Build())
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to create a Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildRequestData object containing the XML project file and a dictionary of std properties like Configuration and Platform.  Then you create a Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters object containing your ProjectCollection object from your code snippet and pass that off to the default Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.

powershell pseudo code:

```
#set build properties
$props = new-object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[[System.String],[System.String]]"
$props.Add("Configuration",$config)
$props.Add("Platform",$platform)

#create the projectCollection
$projectCollection = new-object Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection -argumentList $props,$loggers,"ConfigurationFile,Registry"
$request = new-object Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildRequestData -argumentlist $project,$props,$null,$targets,$null

#create a BuildParameters object to hold the Project Collection
$parameters = new-object Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters -argumentlist @($projectCollection)
$parameters.MaxNodeCount = 1
$parameters.Loggers = $projectCollection.Loggers
$parameters.ToolsetDefinitionLocations = "ConfigurationFile,Registry"
$parameters.DefaultToolsVersion = $toolsVersion

#get the build manager and submit a build request with the appropriate parameters
$manager = [Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager]::DefaultBuildManager 
$result = $manager.Build($parameters, $request)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing project.Load(xmlprojectfile); line in your migrated code. You have to add xmlprojectfile into projectcollection somehow, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a *new* Project with *new* keyword:

```
// var project = new Project(collection);
```

Use this:

```
 var project = collection.LoadProject("myproject.csproj")
```